# GL_ARB_sparse_texture not supported

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-extensions

I have this code which check if `GL_ARB_sparse_texture` is supported:

```
GLint ExtensionCount = 0;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &ExtensionCount);
    for (GLint i = 0; i < ExtensionCount; ++i)
        if (std::string((char const*)glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, i)) == std::string("GL_ARB_sparse_texture")){
            std::cout << "supported" << std::endl;
        }
```

It prints out that it is supported. Problem is that my shader says it is not:

```
#version 450 core
#extension GL_ARB_sparse_texture : require
```

output:
[image]

I have GTX 660Ti with 350.12 drivers on windows 8.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [The `ARB_sparse_texture` spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sparse_texture.txt) doesn't look like it extends GLSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As genpfault said in the comment, only extensions that add features to the GLSL language need to be enabled manually in the shader with the `#extension` directive. Since `GL_ARB_sparse_texture` doesn't add GLSL functionality, you don't need to explicitly enable it in your shaders - checking support with `glGetIntegerv` is enough.

If an extension modifies the GLSL specification (such as [ARB_shader_subroutine](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_subroutine.txt)), it is mentioned in the extension specification.